# UITableViewCell content of previous row is still visible on Cell reload

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` that has 2 different custom `UITableViewCell` with 2 different unique identifiers.

I load the first custom `UITableViewCell` on `Load` and then the second custom `UITableViewCell` on `Cell Select`.

I know that my problem is related to the way I am reusing my Cells. But I've tried using

`routineSearchSelectedResultCell * cell = (routineSearchSelectedResultCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];` and the result is that the new `UITableViewCell` is empty and the properties do not get populated.

I've also tried `[[[cell contentView] subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector: @selector(removeFromSuperview)];` but give me the same results.

How could I go around this problem??

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if (idp && idp.row == indexPath.row  ) {
        return [self tableViewRoutineSelectedResult:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }

    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"routineSearchCell";
    routineSearchCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[routineSearchCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }


    cell.routineName.text = _myDownloadedInfo[@"routines"][indexPath.row][@"routine"][@"routineName"];
    cell.routineAuthor.text = _myDownloadedInfo[@"routines"][indexPath.row][@"routine"][@"username"];

    return cell;

}
- (routineSearchSelectedResultCell *)tableViewRoutineSelectedResult:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSDictionary* myRoutine = _myDownloadedInfo[@"routines"][indexPath.row][@"routine"];

    [self sortOutRoutineImages:myRoutine[@"routineType"]];

    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"routineSearchSelectedResultCell";
    routineSearchSelectedResultCell * cell = (routineSearchSelectedResultCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[routineSearchSelectedResultCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.label1.text =@"test";
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BlackGradientSearch"]];
    cell = [self iconRoutineImagesController:cell];
    cell.imgInstruction.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"InstructionSearchWhite"];
    cell.imgVideos.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"VideoSearchWhite"];
    cell.routineName.text = myRoutine[@"routineName"];
    [cell.download setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DownloadSearchWhite"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    return cell;
}
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if ( idp ) {
        NSIndexPath* pIdp = [[NSIndexPath alloc] init];
        pIdp = idp;
        idp = indexPath;
        [tableView beginUpdates];
        [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
        [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[pIdp] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
        [tableView endUpdates];
    } else {
        idp = [[NSIndexPath alloc]init];
        idp = indexPath;
        [tableView beginUpdates];
        [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
        [tableView endUpdates];
    }



}
```

[image]

Comment: so im assuming you assign `idp.row` on cell selection and then call `reloadData` ?

Comment: I've just added the code of the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: So what is the problem exactly? from the picture is seems the cell is loading. Are you expecting it to go away if you reload?

Comment: The problem is that it loads but it loads on top of the pervious content (see pic). And I do not want to display the previous content.

Comment: Im just curious, if you were to replace the `beginUpdates]... endUpdates]` with `[tableView reloadData]`, would it work? can you give it a try

Comment: same problem. There is no difference.

Answer (score 0):

try to override

```
-(void)prepareForReuse
```

If a UITableViewCell object is reusable—that is, it has a reuse identifier—this method is invoked just before the object is returned from the UITableView method dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:. For performance reasons, you should only reset attributes of the cell that are not related to content, for example, alpha, editing, and selection state. The table view's delegate in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: should always reset all content when reusing a cell. If the cell object does not have an associated reuse identifier, this method is not called. If you override this method, you must be sure to invoke the superclass implementation.

see the [document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the labels and they are overlapping..
Try to use this, It might help you..

```
for(UIView *view in cell.subviews){ 
   if([view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]){
     [view removeFromSuperview];
   } 
}
```